# Render Text in an Image with Not Straight Borders

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, image-processing, noise

How to I render my text with borders not straight, just like the second image? (The font of the two image is different but the way the borders is rendered is of concern.)

[image]

[image]

My initial code is

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
from PIL import ImageFont

from random import seed
from random import randint
import numpy as np
import os.path

#Returns the text size in terms of width and height.
def getSize(txt, font):
    testImg = Image.new('RGB', (1, 1))
    testDraw = ImageDraw.Draw(testImg)
    return testDraw.textsize(txt, font)

text = 'lemper'
fontname = 'arial.ttf'
fontsize= 25

font = ImageFont.truetype(fontname, fontsize)
width, height = getSize(text, font)

#Creates an image with white background of constant size.
img = Image.new('RGB', (100, 100), 'white')
d = ImageDraw.Draw( img)
d.text(get_xy_coordinates(text, font), text, fill='black', font=font)             
img.save("text_images/1.png")
```

Comment: Use another font with a design you like more. Differences between fonts is not a case of "using another way to render it". The actual *design* is different.

Comment: @usr2564301: I don't think the OP means that. She's just saying that the typeface is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to achieve this effect is to use a "displacement function" (X(x, y), Y(x, y)) which moves every pixel to a nearby position. This function should be smooth, with a small amplitude and somewhat irregular. It can be obtained for example by a combination of trigonometric functions with incommensurable periods.

You will have to implement a resampling function, with bilinear interpolation for good quality.

Comment: Is there any Python library that does this functionality?

Comment: @Cubilla: I don't know, I use to program such things myself ;-) But maybe OpenCV's `remap` function.